# Why does my Python code keeps running even after 10 seconds?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, terminate

I have a code that's printing out mouse coordinate **( x, y ) and time stamps** every **100ms** . I want it to **run for 10 seconds**. That's it.

So I implemented "**multiprocessing**" and I initialized it to call the main function **"printevery100ms"** from inside the multiprocessing function and I told it to shut down after 10 seconds.

*But instead of shutting down after 10 seconds, it skips over the p.terminate() command and keeps running and running...*

**Here's the code.**

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import threading
import datetime


def printevery100ms():

    threading.Timer(.1,printevery100ms).start()
    ts = time.time()
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


  from ctypes import windll,Structure,c_int,byref

  class POINT(Structure):

     _fields_ = [("x",c_int),("y",c_int)]

  def queryMousePosition():

      pt = POINT()
      windll.user32.GetCursorPos(byref(pt))
      return {"x": pt.x,"y": pt.y}

  pos = queryMousePosition()

  print('{{\'x\': {}, \'y\': {}}}'.format(pos['x'],pos['y']),st)

printevery100ms()


if __name__ == '__main__':

        # Start printevery100ms as a process
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=printevery100ms, name="printevery100ms", args=(10,))
        p.start()

        # Wait 10 seconds for printevery100ms

        time.sleep(10)
        # Terminate printevery100ms
        p.terminate()

        p.join()
        print "Not Terminated"
```

So the multiprocessing code initializes the 10 second timer and it's supposed to shut it down after 10 seconds which is the purpose of the terminate command. I wrote a print command to print out "Not terminated" if the code doesn't STOP even after 10 seconds ; which is exactly what happened.

**Here is the result :**( after 9 seconds..)

```
("{'x': 1255, 'y': 395}", '2017-01-19 13:31:58')
("{'x': 1255, 'y': 395}", '2017-01-19 13:31:58')
("{'x': 1255, 'y': 395}", '2017-01-19 13:31:58')
Not Terminated
("{'x': 1205, 'y': 399}", '2017-01-19 13:31:58')
("{'x': 961, 'y': 410}", '2017-01-19 13:31:58')
("{'x': 610, 'y': 407}", '2017-01-19 13:31:58')
```

As you can see it's printing "Not terminated " which means it runs for 10 seconds and it get to the terminate command , but keeps on running as if nothing happened. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong or if this has something to do with multi processing?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with you code:

1. From a style perspective, you have differing indents within the `printevery100ms` function.
2. I'm guessing this is the issue: `printevery100ms()` is called before your  `if __name__ == '__main__':` (right about line 30) and runs the function in your main thread and that doesn't stop.
3. The call to `multiprocessing.Process` calls `printevery100ms` with an argument of (10,) which results in this call to fail. However, you still have the main thread running so it doesn't seem like it stops.

Here's the fix:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import threading
import datetime


def printevery100ms():

    threading.Timer(.1,printevery100ms).start()
    ts = time.time()
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


    from ctypes import windll,Structure,c_int,byref

    class POINT(Structure):

        _fields_ = [("x",c_int),("y",c_int)]

    def queryMousePosition():

        pt = POINT()
        windll.user32.GetCursorPos(byref(pt))
        return {"x": pt.x,"y": pt.y}

    pos = queryMousePosition()

    print('{{\'x\': {}, \'y\': {}}}'.format(pos['x'],pos['y']),st)

#printevery100ms() # HERES ISSUE NUMBER 2


if __name__ == '__main__':

        # Start printevery100ms as a process
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=printevery100ms, name="printevery100ms", args=()) # FIXED ISSUE NUMBER 2
        p.start()

        # Wait 10 seconds for printevery100ms

        time.sleep(10)
        # Terminate printevery100ms
        p.terminate()

        p.join()
        print("Not Terminated")
```